# Subsetting and Summing a Data Frame

Tags: r, partitioning, summary

My goal is: given a dataframe of dichotomous responses (e.g., 0s and 1s), how can I produce a summary matrix that: 1) has two columns (one for answering the first question correctly, and the other for answering it incorrectly), and 2) has rows pertaining to the number of individuals obtaining a particular sum score.

For example, say I have 50 respondents, and 5 questions.  This means there are 6 response patterns (all incorrect/0s, then one, two, three, and four correct, and finally all correct/1s). I want the resulting matrix object to look like:

```
... INCORRECT ..... CORRECT   <-- pertaining to a 0 or 1 on the first item respectively

[1]... 10 ............ 0      <-- indicating people who, after responded 0 on the first question, responded 0 on all questions (5 zeroes)
[2]... 8  ............ 2      <-- indicating 12 people who got 1 correct (8 got the first question incorrect, 2 got the first question correct)
[3]... 4 ............. 8      <-- indicating 12 people who got 2 correct (4 got the first question incorrect but got 2 of the other questions correct, 8 got the first question and 1 other correct)
[4]... 6 ............. 3      <-- indicating 9 people who got 3 correct
[5]... 3 ............. 4      <-- indicating 7 people who got 4 correct
[6]... 0 ............. 8      <-- pertaining to the 8 people who answered all 5 questions correctly (necessarily indicating they got the first question correct).
```

My train of thought is that I need to split the dataframe by performance on the first question (working one column at a time) and find the sum scores for each row (participant), then tabulate them into the first column; then do the same for the second?

This is going to be built into a package, so I am trying to figure out how to do this using only base functions.

Here is an example dataset similar to what I will be working with:

```
n <- 50
z <- c(0, 1)
samp.fun <- function(x, n){
    sample(x, n, replace = TRUE)
}

data <- data.frame(0)
for (i in 1:5){
    data[1:n, i] <- samp.fun(z, n)
}
names(data)[1:5] <- c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5")
```

Any thoughts would be extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using @alexwhan's data, here's a `data.table` solution:

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(data)

dt[, list(x1.incorrect=sum(x1==0), x1.correct=sum(x1==1)), keyby=total]
#    total x1.incorrect x1.correct
# 1:     0            2          0
# 2:     1            7          1
# 3:     2            9          8
# 4:     3            7          6
# 5:     4            0          7
# 6:     5            0          3
```

equivalently, you could get the results even more direct, if you don't mind setting the column names later, using `table` with `as.list` as follows:

```
dt[, as.list(table(factor(x1, levels=c(0,1)))), keyby=total]
#    total 0 1
# 1:     0 2 0
# 2:     1 7 1
# 3:     2 9 8
# 4:     3 7 6
# 5:     4 0 7
# 6:     5 0 3
```

Note: You can wrap the `as.list(.)` with `setNames()` like:

```
dt[, setNames(as.list(table(factor(x1, levels=c(0,1)))), 
           c("x1.incorrect", "x1.correct")), keyby = total]
```

to set the column names at one go as well.

Comment: Every time you post, it frustrates me that i haven't had time to learn data.table yet

Comment: @alexwhan, your `ddply` solution could be just: `> ddply(data, .(total), summarise, n=sum(x1==0), y=sum(x1==1))` no? Why not make attempt `data.table` solution? If there's improvement, I can correct you to the best of my knowledge...

Comment: I am going to mark this as solved, although I was hoping to find a solution that didn't require external packages (like data.table, reshape2, or plyr).  Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 3):

Because you didn't use `set.seed` when creating your data, I can't check this solution against your example, but I think it's what you're after. I'm using function from `reshape2` and `plyr` to get summaries of the data.

```
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)
#create data
set.seed(1234)
n <- 50
z <- c(0, 1)
samp.fun <- function(x, n){
  sample(x, n, replace = TRUE)
}

data <- data.frame(0)
for (i in 1:5){
  data[1:n, i] <- samp.fun(z, n)
}
names(data)[1:5] <- c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5")
data$id <- 1:50

#First get the long form to make summaries on
data.m <- melt(data, id.vars="id")

#Get summary to find total correct answers
data.sum <- ddply(data.m, .(id), summarise,
                  total = sum(value))

#merge back with original data to associate with id
data <- merge(data, data.sum)
data$total <- factor(data$total)

#summarise again to get difference between patterns
data.sum2 <- ddply(data, .(total), summarise,
               x1.incorrect = length(total) - sum(x1),
               x1.correct = sum(x1))
data.sum2
#   total x1.incorrect x1.correct
# 1     0            2          0
# 2     1            7          1
# 3     2            9          8
# 4     3            7          6
# 5     4            0          7
# 6     5            0          3
```

Comment: why not just do `rowSums` to compute `total`. Why subset by `id` when they are all unique?

Answer (score -1):

Nice puzzle - if I get it right this should also do it:

```
table(rowSums(data),data[,1])
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not do what I need.  Thanks for the attempt though!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback - however, do you see what seems to be wrong with it? (Using alexwhan's data that was created with `set.seed(1234); n <- 50 ....` my outputs appear similar to Arun's.)